# Sharing and visibility sample question

Tags: sharing

I am preparing for my Sharing and Visibility Designer exam but get through this question. This question is coming from focusonforce

[image]

I feel this answer is kind of strange to me. Since implicit sharing doesn't apply to custom object. Although more than 10k custom object linked to one single account can potentially cause data skew, this has little to do with sharing calculation.

So I personally feel C should be a correct answer instead of A.

I know those answers from websites can potentially be wrong but I am not very sure. So can I get a confirm here?

Comment: Where did you find these practice exam questions?

Comment: @Robs this one is on focusonforce

Comment: @LanceShi Would you mind editing that source prominently into your question? We typically delete exam-type material of unknown provenance out of hand.

Comment: @DavidReed edited as per requested